# Sempre incluir argumentos ao executar docker-compose run

Tags: docker

Tenho uma dúvida em relação à passagem de argumentos no docker-compose run:

Estou usando um [Dockerfile](https://github.com/DockerDemos/appstack-wpcli/blob/master/Dockerfile) que tem o seguinte entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/wp" ]
CMD [ "--allow-root", "--help" ]
```

Eu preciso que o `--allow-root` esteja SEMPRE incluso.

Se eu executo `docker-compose run [service]` o argumento vai por padrão, mas se eu executo `docker-compose run [service] option (option option...)` eu preciso incluir o argumento manualmente.

Tem como ele SEMPRE incluir o argumento? Preciso editar o Dockerfile (não sou o autor) ou dá pra fazer via docker-compose? Tentei o [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) seguindo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366857/how-to-pass-arguments-to-entrypoint-in-docker-compose-yml), mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score -1):

Quando algum argumento é passado para o comando docker-compose run [service] os argumentos subscrevem as configurações descritas no docker-compose.yml como descrito na documentação
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/ .
Não é possível editar o Dockerfile, mas você pode criar um novo Dockerfile que seja derivado e sobrescreva o entrypoint.
Ex:

FROM vendor/image:tag

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/wp", "--allow-root" ]

Dessa forma o parâmetro --allow-root sempre estará presente no entrypoint e os parâmetros passados depois de run serão interpretados junto com entrypoint.

É importante analisar se esse parâmetro no entrypoint não irá impactar no uso da imagem.